If cell contains item from range AND meets criteria in other column in range then return value
I am hoping for further help on my bird research study.  Everyone has been so helpful and I'm using all of your suggestions, it's really helped me get through 6500+ cases!
Here is my new dilemma: I want to check a cell (DIAGNOSIS FOR EACH CASE) to see if it includes any string from a range of items (ALL DIAGNOSES) AND is also marked "Y" for a qualifier (SHOCK, in this example) for that item in the range.
I have tried =IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B,D2:D4)))>0,"Y","N") placed in $C and this has gotten me half way there, but I need this second qualifier and I can't seem to be able to do it by myself.
In this example, Column B is the search-in column, Column D is the range, Column E is the qualifier for the range, and Column C is the desired output. I would prefer to do this without having to convert my data to tables.



CASE
DIAGNOSES FOR EACH CASE
DESIRED OUTPUT
ALL DIAGNOSES (RANGE)
SHOCK (RANGE)




1
SHOCK, PULMONARY; HYPOXIA
Y
SHOCK
Y


2
SHOCK
Y
SHOCK, PULMONARY
Y


3
SHOCK, PULMONARY
Y
HYPOXIA
N


4

N




5
HYPOXIA
N






Here is one way you could try :


=IF(OR(IFERROR(SEARCH($D$2:$D$4,TEXTSPLIT(B2,"; ")),0)*($E$2:$E$4="Y")),"Y","N")


Or, If you like to return it for the whole array then:
=MAP(B2:B6,LAMBDA(x,IF(OR(IFERROR(SEARCH(D2:D4,TEXTSPLIT(x,"; ")),0)*(E2:E4="Y")),"Y","N")))


Can use the TEXT() function to return the Y and N as well or custom formatting like in last query:
=TEXT(N(OR(IFERROR(SEARCH($D$2:$D$4,TEXTSPLIT(B2,"; ")),0)*($E$2:$E$4="Y"))),"[=1]\Y;\N")


Also, if applicable can make use of the newer function available in MS365 Office Insiders, TRIMRANGE() or its features.
=LET(
     _Search, DROP(B.:.B,1),
     _Range, DROP(D.:.E,1),
     MAP(_Search,LAMBDA(x,
     IF(OR(IFERROR(SEARCH(TAKE(_Range,,1),TEXTSPLIT(x,"; ")),0)*
          (DROP(_Range,,1)="Y")),"Y","N"))))



Thank you!  Trying out all permutations now.  Without the whole array option then this will be challenging for all 6500 cases.  Perhaps there is an option if the RANGE data (columns D and E) are in a table?  THANK YOU!

@LaurenP yes. shouldn;t be a problem. you just select the specific column to apply. Also I tried to stick to the reference in the post I would prefer to do this without having to convert my data to tables.

Selecting the specific column to apply worked beautifuly, perfectly!  It achieved my goal of not having to convert data to tables.  I didn't say this but should have, I also was hoping for a solution that would not require an array so that I can later sort my data.  It seems that I can't sort data that has an array applied to it.  Thank you so much!

@LaurenP if you happen to use the first method, then you can sort the data, it wont require additional sort function, and it wont be an array as well. try and let me know. it will help me to help you more better. You can use native sort feature of excel on an array. suggested to use the first one. its simple formula and easy to debug.


filter "ALL DIAGNOSES" and sort  for faster lookup with XMATCH
split each diagnoses entry by ' and lookup
at least one is matched if
SUM(--ISNUMBER(XMATCH(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(d_e, {",",";"})), all_diag > 0

enter in C2 (and adjust the ranges to match your data):
=LET(
    include_for_shock, E2:E100 = "Y",
    all_diag, SORT(TRIM(FILTER(D2:D100, include_for_shock))),
    diag_for_each, B2:B100,
    includes_diag, MAP(diag_for_each, LAMBDA(d_e,
            IF( ISBLANK(d_e),0, SUM(--ISNUMBER(XMATCH(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(d_e, ";")), all_diag, , 2))) ))
    ),
    IFS(ISBLANK(diag_for_each), "", includes_diag, "Y", TRUE, "N")
)



Thank you @nkalvi!  This worked quite well too! I was hoping for a solution without an array or table, but it looks like the array (lamba) option is probably the best solution.  Thanks again, you've been a huge help to this project!
